# fail to change placeholder color with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, placeholder

Two questions:

1. I am trying to make the placeholder text white. But it doesn't work. I am using Bootstrap 3. [**`JSFiddle demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/G7mzL/9/)
2. Another question is how do I change placeholder color not globally. That is, I have multiple fields, I want only one field to have white placeholder, all the others remain in default color.

html:

```
<form id="search-form" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="">
        <div class="right-inner-addon"> <i class="icon-search search-submit"></i>
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

css:

```
.right-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;
    background-color:#303030;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:white;

}
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    /*  pointer-events: none; */
    cursor: pointer;
    color:white;
}


/* do not group these rules*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: white; }
FF 4-18 
:-moz-placeholder           { color: white; }
 FF 19+
::-moz-placeholder          { color: white; }
 IE 10+
:-ms-input-placeholder      { color: white; }
```

Comment: Note to future readers: "_Two questions:_" We generally don't do that here. Where reasonably possible, there should only be one question per question post. Don't take this question as a precedent.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Assign the placeholder to a class selector like this:

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: white; }  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: white; }  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
.form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: white; }  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }  /* Microsoft Edge */
```

It will work then since a stronger selector was probably overriding your global. I'm on a tablet so i cant inspect and confirm which stronger selector it was :) But it does work I tried it in your fiddle.

This also answers your second question. By assigning it to a class or id and giving an input only that class you can control what inputs to style.

Comment: This is great simple answer. Fiddle Demo for others: http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/G7mzL/11/

Comment: Any ideas why you can't join all this togther seperted by commar?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia this answer explains why you apparently can't join the rules with a comma: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741

Answer (score 22):

There was an issue posted here about this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14107

The issue was solved by this commit: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bd292ca3b89da982abf34473318c77ace3417fb5

The solution therefore is to override it back to `#999` and not `white` as suggested (and also overriding all bootstraps styles, not just for webkit-styles):

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### A Possible Gotcha

**Recommended Sanity Check** - Make sure to add the `form-control` class to your inputs.

If you have bootstrap css loaded on your page, but your inputs don't have the
 `class="form-control"` then placeholder CSS  selector won't apply to them.

Example markup from [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):

[image]

I know this didn't apply to the OP's markup but as I missed this at first and spent a little bit of effort trying to debug it, I'm posting this answer to help others.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Dennis Puzak's solution does not work for me.

The next solution works for me

```
.form-control::placeholder { color: white;} /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera*/
:-ms-input-placeholder.form-control { color: white; }  /* Internet Explorer*/
.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder { color: white; }  /* Microsoft Edge*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap has 3 lines of CSS, within your bootstrap.css generated file that control the placeholder text color:

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
```

Now if you add this to your own CSS file it won't override bootstrap's because it is less specific. So assmuning your form inside a  then add that to your CSS:

```
form .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
form .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
form .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Voila that will override bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The others did not work in my case (Bootstrap 4). Here is the solution I used.

```
html .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:white; }
html .form-control:-moz-placeholder { color:white; }
html .form-control::-moz-placeholder { color:white; }
html .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color:white; }
```

If we use a stronger selector (`html` first), we don't need to use the hacky value `!important`.

This overrides bootstraps CSS as we use a higher level of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to target .form-control elements (`html` first instead of `.form-control` first).

Answer (score 2):

I think qwertzman is on the right track for the best solution to this.

If you only wanted to style a specific placeholder, then his answer still holds true.

But if you want to override the colour of **all** placeholders, (which is more probable) and if you are already compiling your own custom Bootstrap LESS, the answer is even simpler!

Override this LESS variable:
`@input-color-placeholder`

Answer (score 2):

Boostrap Placeholder Mixin:

```
@mixin placeholder($color: $input-color-placeholder) {
  // Firefox
  &::-moz-placeholder {
    color: $color;
    opacity: 1; // Override Firefox's unusual default opacity; see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11526
  }
  &:-ms-input-placeholder { color: $color; } // Internet Explorer 10+
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: $color; } // Safari and Chrome
}
```

now call it:

```
@include placeholder($white);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this answer : [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Work on most browser, the solution in this thread is not working on FF 30+ for example

Answer (score 1):

With **LESS** the actual mixin is in vendor-prefixes.less

```
.placeholder(@color: @input-color-placeholder) {
...
}
```

This mixin is called in forms.less on line 133:

```
.placeholder();
```

Your solution in LESS is:

```
.placeholder(#fff);
```

Imho the best way to go. Just use Winless or a composer compiler like Gulp/Grunt works, too and even better/faster.